# How to filter files when opening using NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans

I'm looking for a way to filter files in an "Open" window. I'm using NetBeans IDE 6.5.
I did some research, and this is what i came up with, but for some reason it's not working.

//global variable
protected static FileFilter myfilter;

//in declaration of variables
fchoLoad.setFileFilter(myfilter);

//inside main
myfilter = .... (i actually delted this part by accident, i need to filter only .fwd files. can anybody tell me what goes here?)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you want to create your own file chooser and be able to filter just some files (.fwd in your case). I guess this is more general Java question (not only NetBeans) and I suggest reading this [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#filters)

Anyway, your "myfilter" should look like this:

```
myfilter = new FileFilter() {

            public boolean accept(File f) {
                return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".fwd")
                        || f.isDirectory();
            }

            public String getDescription() {
                return "FWD Files"; //type any description you want to display
            }
        };
```

Hope that helps